# iwlist returns Interface cannot scan error on Kali Linux 2020 Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox, debian, kali-linux

I've been learning Pentesting recently and have come into a problem relating to the `iwlist and airmon-ng`. My VirtualBox Kali Linux only detects wired connections (despite my host system actually running off a wifi dongle), and so when I use iwconfig I get a `eth0 and lo: no wireless extensions.` Using `ifconfig` puts all my network data into the `eth0` (ethernet) connection.

Searching for this solution online has shown that this is normal for VirtualBox, and as I can still use some network facilities this isn't an issue. But the problem I have is that both the books i've been using require use of airmon-ng and iwlist at some point.

However, when I try to use wireless scans such as `iwlist eth0 scan` I get the `Interface doesn't support scanning error`. I've also tried it with `wlan0` for good measure but I get the same error.

I've tried a few online solutions but nothing seems to work. I've tried the eth0 up or wlan0 up solutions which doesn't work. I've tried installing and using some compat-2010-06 file which seemed to get something up on `aircrack-ng`:

```
phy0    wlan0           mac80211_hwsim  Software simulator of 802.11 radio(s) for mac80211
```

However, `ifconfig wlan0` doesn't provide any proper information, and the WiFi network still doesn't detect nearby networks. Furthermore, using iwlist wlan0 scan still doesnt work, instead it waits a minute before returning "No scan results".

Without the compat file installed, checking airmon-ng returns nothing except a bunch of empty fields.

I've also done "Bridged Adaptor" and selected my wifi adaptor, but this doesn't work help either.

Finally, I should mention that this is all been done as root.

I did also try this using a VMware virtual machine but I still got the same error.
Does anybody know how I can get this all to work properly?

Comment: I should add that I do have a wifi USB adaptor plugged into my computer, specifically the TP-Link TL-WN722N.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a USB Wireless Adapter to your computer

Make sure you can manage USB Pass Through in your VB host to your Kali Guest.

Then make sure the Wireless Adapter you choose has Linux / Kali Drivers.

Once installed as above, you should be able to use it inside Kali.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps i've made a mistake, but I followed the tutorial on this website [https://www.eltima.com/article/virtualbox-usb-passthrough/] and whilst I didn't find the name of my adaptor I did find a Realtek 802.11n NIC which I added to the USB device filters list. When I launch the Kali Machine my wifi on my Windows disconnects (which is expected), but I still cannot get Kali to recognize the wireless adaptor, and now I cannot even connect to the internet through Kali iteself. Finding drivers for my specific TP link comes up empty, I read one forum post saying it works out the box.

Comment: You need an adapter that has drivers for Kali otherwise Kali will not be able to use it.

Comment: Yeah that turned out to be the issue, I had a TP-Link V2 which doesn't have Kali drivers like V1 did. I'm having issues installing linux drivers for my other adaptor, but I should probably open a new question for that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this for myself.

If using VMBox & USB dongle:

- Select VM
- Settings
- USB
- Add USB Dongle to list of devices
- Boot VM
- Top bar: Devices > USB > Enable your device.

Silly little issue that took me longer than I would have liked to resolve.